# Understanding nested for/in loops with "ipairs"

Tags: lua, lua-table

Can some body help me to understand this piece of code?

```
local dev
for _, dev in ipairs(devices) do
        local net
        for _, net in ipairs(dev:get_wifinets()) do
                netlist[#netlist+1] = net:id()
                netdevs[net:id()] = dev:name()
        end
end
```

Comment: Please tell us what parts of the code you don't understand and what parts you do so people can focus on that.

Comment: Emphasizing what @Josh pointed out, `local dev` and `local net` statements are less than not needed; They create unused variables. A `for` statement automatically creates its loop control variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Broken down, it works like this.

```
local dev
```

Not really needed, but I'd imagine you know it creates local variable `dev`.

```
for _, dev in ipairs(devices) do
```

Loops through indexed table `devices`, and stores the value into `dev` locally.

```
local net
```

Again, not really needed.

```
    for _, net in ipairs(dev:get_wifinets()) do
```

`dev` uses the function `get_wifinets()`, which in turns returns an indexed table for which `net` loops through as the value.

```
            netlist[#netlist+1] = net:id()
```

This uses the `id()` function on the value `net` from the table returned with `get_wifinets()` and stores it as the last element in the `netlist` table.

```
           netdevs[net:id()] = dev:name()
```

Since we are still within the scope of the `dev` value loop, this takes the `name()` function of the `dev` value and stores it to the table listed, whether indexed or dictionary.

Hopefully this helps answer your question.